# Removing the space before and after the number

Tags: python

This is the code

```
for x in range(1, 30):
    print"www.interpol.com/file/",x,'/en'
```

It prints this

```
www.interpol.com/file/ 1 /en
www.interpol.com/file/ 2 /en
www.interpol.com/file/ 3 /en
```

but i want to remove the spaces and want the result like

```
www.interpol.com/file/1/en
www.interpol.com/file/2/en
www.interpol.com/file/3/en
```

I think we can use `/b` or special characters like `'`

And if the want the result like this
It worked, thanks. But I have one more question.
Suppose I want the result to be like

```
www.interpol.com/file/30/en
www.interpol.com/file/60/en
www.interpol.com/file/90/en
www.interpol.com/file/120/en
```

then how to do that?
This code worked :

```
> for x in range(1, 30):
>     print("www.interpol.com/file/{}/en".format(x))
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Do you mean `for x in range(30, 121, 30)`? The third keyword argument is the step width, 121 because the end is non-inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the string's `format` method:

```
for x in range(1, 30):
    print("www.interpol.com/file/{}/en".format(x))
```

Comment: It worked , Thanks . But i got one more question.
Suppose i want the result to be like 
www.interpol.com/file/30/en
www.interpol.com/file/60/en
www.interpol.com/file/90/en
then how to do that?

Comment: In Python 3 (or Python 2 if you put `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file), you can do `print("www.interpol.com/file/{}/en".format(x), end=" ")` to replace the newline with a space

Comment: in python2 you can add `,` after the last element. Ending a print statement with a comma omits the newline

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` and cast `x` to `str` (I'm assuming this is Python):

```
>>> for x in range(1, 30):
        print("www.interpol.com/file/" + str(x) + '/en')


'www.interpol.com/file/1/en'
'www.interpol.com/file/2/en'

...
```

Comment: Haha wow I didn't actually even think of that. You're right I'll edit

Comment: str(x) is not casting, it is creating a str type with value x.  A new object is created.  Casting is telling the compiler that the data in memory is to be considered as a certain type.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python3:**

The easiest way to do this is to use the `sep=''` flag:

```
for x in range(1, 30):
    print("www.interpol.com/file/",x,'/en', sep='')
```

**In Python2, you need to import the new print function first:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

which customizes the separator between items in a print statement.

Comment: requires `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2

Comment: True, I was thinking Python3